# compile time error in angular 2 :unreachable code

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular2-services, es6-promise

At this line it shows  unreachable code

```
resolve(data)
```

What is causing this?

My code:

```
  zipCodeBlurEventCall(zipcode) {
    if (!this.validationService.isValidZipCodeRequired(this.siteDetail.ZipCode)) {
        this.clearInvalidFlags();
        this.invalidZipCode = true;
        this.siteDetail.WeatherLocation = "";
        this.toastr.error("Please enter valid Zip Code");
    }
    else {            
        this.siteLoading = true;
        this.queryString = "?zipcode=" + zipcode;

         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.siteService.getStationByZipCode(this.queryString).then(data => {
                this.element = data;

                if (this.element == null) {
                    this.siteLoading = false;
                    this.invalidZipCode = true;
                    this.toastr.error("Invalid Zip Code");
                    return true;

                } else {
                    this.siteDetail.StateName = this.states.find(item => item.StateId === this.siteDetail.StateId).StateName;
                    if (this.siteDetail.StateName.toLowerCase() == this.element.response.place.stateFull.toLowerCase()) {

                        this.siteDetail.WeatherLocation = this.element.response.place.name;
                        this.isWeatherFlag = true;
                        this.siteLoading = false;
                        this.invalidZipCode = false;
                        return false;
                    }

                    else {
                        this.siteLoading = false;
                        this.invalidZipCode = true;
                        this.toastr.error("Zip code does not match with the selected State");
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                resolve(data);                 
          });

    });            

    } 
}
```

Comment: I just woke up, but it appears as though you always return before `resolve` can be reached, meaning it will never be run. Your braces are kind of wonky though, so it's hard to tell just by looking at them what the scoping is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are returning the "true" or "false" Values here, but if you still want your code to work you can do as follows, where you return from the function after resolve is called :

```
  zipCodeBlurEventCall(zipcode) {
    if (!this.validationService.isValidZipCodeRequired(this.siteDetail.ZipCode)) {
        this.clearInvalidFlags();
        this.invalidZipCode = true;
        this.siteDetail.WeatherLocation = "";
        this.toastr.error("Please enter valid Zip Code");
    }
    else {            
        this.siteLoading = true;
        this.queryString = "?zipcode=" + zipcode;

         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.siteService.getStationByZipCode(this.queryString).then(data => {
                this.element = data;
                let returnVal;
                if (this.element == null) {
                    this.siteLoading = false;
                    this.invalidZipCode = true;
                    this.toastr.error("Invalid Zip Code");
                    returnVal = true;

                } else {
                    this.siteDetail.StateName = this.states.find(item => item.StateId === this.siteDetail.StateId).StateName;
                    if (this.siteDetail.StateName.toLowerCase() == this.element.response.place.stateFull.toLowerCase()) {

                        this.siteDetail.WeatherLocation = this.element.response.place.name;
                        this.isWeatherFlag = true;
                        this.siteLoading = false;
                        this.invalidZipCode = false;
                        returnVal = false;
                    }

                    else {
                        this.siteLoading = false;
                        this.invalidZipCode = true;
                        this.toastr.error("Zip code does not match with the selected State");
                        returnVal = true;
                    }
                }

                resolve(data);
                return returnVal;               
          });

    });            

    } 
}
```